# Encoding issue when reading .eml file from MailBee

Tags: c#, encoding, base64

This has to do with a mailing tool we use: MailBee, which is pretty easy to use.

1. We create a Mailing (define the message body and attachments if needed)
2. We create a list of contacts and add this to a DataTable
3. We call MailBee's AddJob method which generates an .eml file in ANSI format
4. After writing the files is completed, we read the files and find the `To:` string using: `Match match = Regex.Match(recipient, @"""(.*?)"" <(.*?)>");`

This value seems to be base64 encoded. Here is my code to unit test the parsing.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        TestMethods.DecodeString("To: \"=?utf-8?B?QWJkdXJyYWhpbSDvv716Z2Vub2dsdQ==?=\" <email@somehost.com;;>");
        // This results in "Abdurrahim �zgenoglu" while it should be "Abdurrahim Özgenoglu"
    }
}

public class TestMethods {
    public static string DecodeString(string stringToDecode)
    {
        Match base64Match = Regex.Match(stringToDecode, @"=\?utf-8\?B\?(.*)\?=");
        if (base64Match.Success)
        {
            string encodedName = base64Match.Groups[1].Value;
            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedName);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
        }

        return stringToDecode;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on what could be going wrong here? I suspect something that MailBee does right before it converts the text into base64. But I can't verify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this decoding wasn't working was that the string being encoded by Mailbee was wrong from the beginning.

What I did find was that you can specify the RequestEncoding and ResponseEncoding of mailbee, which I set to `Encoding.UTF8`.

Anyway, It's solved when I did this and made sure the imported CSV containing the names was in UTF8 in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to convert an ANSI string to UTF-8. That's why you're seeing this error.

Instead of...

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Try using:

```
Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(bytes);
```

Or

```
Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(bytes);
```

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)

Comment: I've tried this before, but then I got ??? instead of the weird symbol: `Abdurrahim ???zgenoglu`. The file is indeed in ANSI but the base64 encoding originates from UTF8 as far as I understood.

Comment: I must correct myself, both solutions return `Abdurrahim ï¿½zgenoglu`